# Issue regarding Turkish e-visa?

Tags: turkey, e-visas

When I click on the confirmation email after entering all details on evisa.gov.tr it says "Unfortunately, we are not able to issue e-Visa for you."

Yesterday it was working perfectly and the payment page loaded without any issue, but due to some reasons I haven't paid. Should I wait for 48 hours and try my luck again? I have a valid UK visitor visa.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [FAQ page](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/) on the Turkish government eVisa web site where this question appears:

> I am notified by the system that my e-Visa application cannot be processed. What should I do?

To which the answer is:

> You can visit the nearest Turkish Embassy or Consulate for your visa application

You can wait 48 hours and try again, but it looks like you don't qualify for an eVisa and you'll have to apply in the usual way.

(No, I don't know why. Maybe Turkish immigration can answer that question)

Comment: Issue resolved. Thank you so much 